# Center parent div vertically based on child element

Tags: html, css, centering

I am hoping to center my parent div height based on my child div height. My goal is to have 3 boxes with a shorter, but wider rectangle centered vertically behind it. Right now I have my parent div shorter and wider than the children, however I cannot seem to center it vertically.

Here is the ideal outcome:
[image: my ideal outcome]

Here is my current version (Please ignore minor differences with text and box colors). :
[image: current version]

```css
.content {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}


#container .col {
    border: 1px solid #00acd4;
    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    position: relative;
}

#parent {
    background-color: #f0f9fb;
    max-height: 80px;
}

#container {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col ">

          <h3>$500</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-1 col">

          <h3>$3500</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col offset-1">

          <h3>50%</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a sketch of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Also, make sure you are CLOSING your `<h3>` tags...

Comment: @JustinSt.Germain it would look very similar to my js fiddle except with the blue background being vertically centered instead of sitting at the top (so imagine it with about 20px margin spacing on top, without the boxes moving). I am thinking the solution might be working the absolute positioning in the child tags but I'm not sure!

Comment: So, FYI, the fiddle and the snippet are displaying differently for me-- the snippet has your boxes stacked vertically, while in your fiddle they are all lined up in a horizontal line.  I think ideally we want the snippet on the question to be the ultimate source of truth, that way if the fiddle were to change or `404` we would still have a reference to the code that provides context to the question.

Comment: @AlexanderNied I noticed the same thing when I went to answer the questions. I would recommend utilizing flexbox vs the initial way that is presented in the fiddle.

Comment: @AlexanderNied sorry about that! I didn't mean to add a snippet, just the code. The snippet won't stack correctly because I'm using the bootstrap library

Comment: @Betsy try to stay away from absolute positioning. You are getting inconsistent behavior already between JSFiddle and StackOverflow. You really should look into some better techniques like flexbox. I will make a snippet for that too separate from the fiddle update I already provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a negative margin unless absolutely necessary. In this case, it is not. Use `flex` on `parent` with `align-items: center;`

```css
.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#container .col {
  border: 1px solid #00acd4;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

#parent {
  background-color: #f0f9fb;
  max-height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col ">

          <h3>$500</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-1 col">

          <h3>$3500</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col offset-1">

          <h3>50%</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a sketch of what you are trying to do, I believe this is what you are wanting... You can just set a negative margin in the `col` divs in order to take them outside of the parent...

```css
#container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#parent {
  background-color: #f0f9fb;
}

.content {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

#container .col {
  border: 1px solid #00acd4;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h3>$500</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="offset-1 col">
          <h3>$3500</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="col offset-1">
          <h3>50%</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Forked your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jstgermain/o6xhL92s/

*** RECOMMEND BELOW SOLUTION ***

@Betsy, I would recommend simplifying your HTML and using flexbox over the previous solution to your fiddle. You will want to make sure your behavior is consistent across browsers and devices. You can use media queries to change the size to eht `col` items for smaller devices.

```css
#container {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#parent {
  background-color: red;
  /*#f0f9fb;*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.col {
  border: 1px solid #00acd4;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 25%;
  margin: -20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="parent">
    <div class="col">
      <h3>$500</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <h3>$3500</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <h3>50%</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! In this case, I think that simplification is a worse solution for me. .col is a bootstrap class I'm using in more than one place. I prefer to use #container .col because the custom code will only be used in that one spot and would not mess up other parts of my code. In this case, I think it's a bit counter intuitive to apply styling to '.col' in a mediaquery because I can use col-lg-4 or something similar if I want it to appear as a full column on mobile but be different on desktop. 
Is there any large drawbacks that you have for using the 'offset-' bootstrap class?

Comment: @Betsy, yeah, don’t use the simplified one if using bootstrap. 